# From where nagios run custom plugins

Tags: nagios

I am using nagios 3.2 for monitoring. I have a custom plug-in which I have placed in...

/usr/local/nagios/libexec, for nagios monitoring.

My custom plugin reads a configuration file for functioning properly. and this configuration file should be in the same directory.

Form this directory(../nagios/libexec), I am able to execute the binary.

However when nagios try to run it, it is not able to read associated configuration file.

Troubleshooting tried:-

1.) I have given full privileges to both binary and configuration file

-rwsrwxrwx  1 root    root      2102 Mar  7 04:53 ------.properties
-rwsrwxrwx  1 root    root   2079462 Mar  6 12:03 binary

Please let me know if nagios run the custom plugin from any other directory?
or any other suggestion...

Thanks,
Ruchir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I am able to find out by replacing by plugin with a scripts that gives directory (PWD)
and find out that it is running nagios daemon from / (root) directory.

So I have placed my configuration file there and it worked.

Thanks everone for your suggestions!!!

Answer (score 5):

Check /usr/local/nagios/etc/resource.cfg $USER1$ variable. It points to plugin directory.
Does your plugin need any privileges to access an specific dir or something? Maybe nagios user doesn't have access to it, or you need to add nagios to sudoers.

Answer (score 1):

What language is this plugin written in (this sometimes makes a difference in how the plugin will handle your environment vars)?  Have you tried using the FULL path to your configuration file, in the plugin (not just "./conffile)?  If you su to the Nagios user and attempt to execute said plugin (with config), does it work?